# Maven compiler error: Duplicate name in Manifest: Depends-On

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, manifest

I am trying to convert a legacy monolith project (MAIN) into Maven which has over 125 dependencies, added over years of development.

During install I am getting below error, which fails the build.

How Do I get to know which jar among 125 is causing the problem.

Build being prepared with Eclipse IDE, JDK 1.8.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project MyBatch: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Oct 08, 2017 5:[32,-1] 2 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
[ERROR] WARNING: Duplicate name in Manifest: Depends-On.
[ERROR] Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and
```

Ironically, My build started failing since last morning, prior to which this was completely working well. I added no additional dependencies, no confguration params changed. I have even tried reverting my pom.xml to previous version (which was working fine) but thats also didnt help.

**Any directions please ?**

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.apps</groupId>
    <artifactId>dev-main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>dev-main</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/javaroot</sourceDirectory>
         <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/resources/</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <meminitial>512m</meminitial>
                    <maxmem>1048m</maxmem>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com/myorg/oasys/services/notes/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>com/myorg/corp/gdcms/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>com/myorg/ejb/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>itext</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jctableK</groupId>
            <artifactId>jctableK</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>mqjms</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jconn3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bea.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
            <version>9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>wljmsclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>wljmsclient</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.04</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>serializer</groupId>
            <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fox-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>OpenFX-security-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>OpenFX-security-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fox-security-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>tibjms</groupId>
            <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>prodapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>prodapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>eaeUtil</groupId>
            <artifactId>eaeUtil</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>quantum</groupId>
            <artifactId>quantum</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jxl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>tibrvj</groupId>
            <artifactId>tibrvj</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>rdsMarsClient</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdsMarsClient</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>sjsxp</groupId>
            <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>rsgfientities</groupId>
            <artifactId>rsgfientities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mrbean</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-smile</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxb-commons-lang-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-commons-lang-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>dspModelClient</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>dspModelBase</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>gfi_gemfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gfi_gemfire</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>gemfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gemfire</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>httpcore</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan-j</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fop</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>0.93</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>gfinet</groupId>
            <artifactId>gfinet_config</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>gfinet</groupId>
            <artifactId>gfinet_messaging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>rdsclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdsclient</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>FpML-JAXB</groupId>
            <artifactId>FpML-JAXB</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>T-ZeroAPI</groupId>
            <artifactId>T-ZeroAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bouncycastle-jce-jdk13-112cx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jnlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnlp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-smile</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>ALWrapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>ALWrapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>AnalyticsLibrary</groupId>
            <artifactId>AnalyticsLibrary</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-cache-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxrs-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-release-with-junit-easymock-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myorg.161090.rio_umb</groupId>
            <artifactId>rio_umb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0_G3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myorg.161090.rio_umb</groupId>
            <artifactId>rio_registryservice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0_G3</version>
        </dependency>
 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- this is for resolving sonar Class not found -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose.aspose-words</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
            <version>14.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
 -->        <dependency>
          <groupId>tangosol</groupId>
          <artifactId>tangosol</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Update 1:** I managed to extract MANIFEST.MF from all dependent jars; but none contains "Depends-on".

Comment: Currently, you probably have some jar on your classpath with an older version of jdk.

Comment: Would you share the pom.xml file ?

Comment: @nullpointer - there are many jars which are build over jdk 1.2 - 1.5.

Comment: As @nullpointer said, you should check your dependencies that were compiled with 1.2 or 1.3 since the MANIFEST checking was introduced with 1.4 and above.